# usb data transfer to external usb 3

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I bought a usb external drive and every time I try to copy to it I get lockup when 1.8 GB has been transferred and I can't cancel copy. Reboot required to clear it.

If I copy smaller chunks than 1.8 GB then it works and if I copy several smaller chunks, more than 1.8 GB in total is saved to usb disk no problem. It is only when I try to copy a folder with total of more than 1.8 GB that it fails at 1.8 GB of current transfer.

Running windows 7 64bit with USB2 ports and USB3 HGST Touro mobile pro 1TB external drive which is supposed to be usb 2 compliant. Drive formated using NTFS 4096 blocks size.

Any ideas why transfer would fail for anything bigger than 1.8 GB and is there anything I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

More hardware specs might help. For instance issues such have this have been observed on systems with NVIDIA USB EHCI chipsets: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976972

Comment: specs here

http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02674501-31%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=5035310&ac.admitted=1390437183934.876444892.199480143

Comment: tried that kb hotfix and it said not applicable so no go with that

Comment: just to clean up my old question...
Problem was some bd sectors on my hard drive. Cleaned those up and all worked fine.